# convertir longitud y latitud a direccion geografica

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5, ionic

Amigos quiero convertir la longitud y latitud que obtengo con este código a dirección geográfica

```js
.controller('CtrlUbi', function($scope) {  
  if (navigator.geolocation) {  
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
      $scope.$apply(function() {  
        $scope.position = position;  
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);  
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);  
        console.log(position)  
      });  
    });  
  }  
});
```

Comment: Has jugado con la API de Google Maps? Qué has intentado? Has investigado algo sobre el tema?

Answer (score 1):

Tecnicamente, `position` ya es una dirección geográfica.

Ahora bien, si lo que necesitas es crear un objeto compatible con la APIv3 de google maps, se hace de esta manera:

```
var miDireccion = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

Si necesitas centrar el mapa respecto a esta posición:

```
miGoogleMap.setCenter(miDireccion);
```

Si lo que quieres es mostrarlo en el mapa como un marcador:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : miDireccion,
        map      : miGoogleMap,
        title    : "Mi marcador",
});
```

Si quieres mostrar más de un marcador en el mapa y modificarlos o dar mas información, conserva un array de marcadores como variable global (`var markers [];`) e inserta cada marcador alli para conservarlo `markers.push(marker)`.

Answer (score 0):

este codigo te servirá para devolver una dirección al obtener directamente la latitud y longitud

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {    
         $scope.createMarker(map);
         $scope.posicion_actual = {
           lat: position.coords.latitude,
           lng: position.coords.longitude
         }; 

         var geocoding ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + $scope.posicion_actual.lat + ',' + $scope.posicion_actual.lng + '&sensor=false';
         console.log(geocoding);

         $.getJSON(geocoding).done(function(location) {
            console.log(location.results[0].formatted_address);
            $scope.search_entidad = location.results[0].formatted_address;
            $scope.$digest();
         });
}
```